# How can I put the sheet name into a cell without using ws.load("name")?

Tags: excel, office-js

I am having trouble accessing the sheet name in the local scope of the function.

Is there something I am missing?

```
      Excel.run(function (context) {

          //get the active worksheet
          var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet()

          /* this code does not work
          var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
          range.values = ws.name;
          */

          //this will work
          ws.load("name");

          return context.sync()
              .then(function () {
                  var range2 = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
                  range2.values = ws.name;
              });

      });
```

Comment: use ! to refer from other sheet, like =sheet1!A1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with the code shown above. The scenario you are describing is to assign the active worksheet name to the selected cell (assuming user has only selected single cell). Prior to using the worksheet's `name` property, you have to load it and call `context.sync` to execute the instructions. Until then, the add-in doesn't know what the actual value of worksheet is. Then, you assign the range value as 2-D array since cell and range are basically the same object in Excel. I don't know what you are trying to do in the .then() function in your code. You can very well do that before your last sync() call as there is no dependency between previous calls. Code below shows the top part of your requirement. I'm just using await syntax instead of .then (basically the same effect).

```
async function run() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        ws.load('name');
        await context.sync();
        const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        range.values = [[ws.name]];
        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

Comment: +1. Also, for a more detailed explanation of sync() and load(), see this page in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-core-concepts#proxy-objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're missing anything. This is how it is supposed to work. The variable `ws` is just a proxy object until you load it and sync. When you want to read a property of an object, you have to load it and sync to bring the object properties that you want to read from the document to your add-in.